# Using the proper tense

Tags: grammar, tense, reported-speech

> - He **mentioned** that he ........ problems at home, but he didn't explain. However, reading between the lines, I guess his relationship with his wife is not as nice as it used to be.

**a. has** (while he has the problem yest.) 
**b. had** (while verbs used in a sentence should all be the same tense.)

I was wondering what is the correct choice here.

Logically, "a" and grammatically "b" seems to be alright here. Nevertheless, I have my doubts yet.

Comment: Both are correct. If this was a test question which accepted only one answer, then the question is faulty.

Comment: I wonder whether it's from the same test as https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/573672/what-would-be-the-most-appropriate-word-to-fill-the-gap —same fault!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sentence shows that two tenses are already being used: the conversation was in the past, but “his relationship… is” in the present. So “He mentioned that he had” is valid; it keeps the conversation in the past tense. And “He mentioned that he has” could also be valid; it emphasizes the fact that the same problems he had (then) are still ongoing (now). Without the second sentence, this would be a less obvious choice, and potentially confusing to read.